# Customize spinner that is in the menu or Action Bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-spinner

I know how to customize the spinner. In my case it is a little bit different. I cannot modify my code more than I have now. Normally, I am able to make spinner that is reachable from all activities in my app.
I am trying to put icon along the textview in the spinner drop down.
Here the code I have;

Spinner.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:prompt="@string/language_prompt" />
```

spinner_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="17sp" >
 </TextView>

 <!-- Here I cannot use Relative layout. If I use it gives error like [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView]. Without layout I cannot implement ImageView. I am stuck here.
```

My activity class;

```
public class Base_Activity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //int flags = R.array.flags;

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.getItem(0).getActionView()
            .findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.languages, R.layout.spinner_row);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

What I want is to make is custom Adapter so that I can put image along the textview in spinner list. I am not able to make normal way that I checked in many tutorials. I think it's because I am creating spinner in onCreateOptionsMenu() constructor.

Comment: Have you tried making a custom `Adapter`? Extending `ArrayAdapter` would be a good start.

Comment: you know that `TextView` can have `drawable` element, no?

Comment: @Ole For sure I did that.

Comment: @cosmincalistru I guess he wants different images for each row in the `Spinner`. To achieve that, he needs a custom `Adapter`.

Comment: @Ole Exactly!! You are right. Lists of country along with their respective flags.

Comment: @cosmincalistru It is possible to do as you are saying also. But in my case I am using whole layout not just a textview to get the array of items.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/) could help

Comment: @bShah : is ur spinner present in `action bar` or in `activity as a widget`

Comment: @kaushik: Yeah it is presented in action bar

Comment: @cosmincalistru I tried that way as well but do not let me to extend base adapter or array adapter.

Comment: Or, is it possible to do from the xml file.. mapping two items each other from different arrays. If yes, how??

Answer (score 1):

u can take a look at this [tutorial on `AndroidHive`](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

code snippet

```
// Spinner title navigation data
        navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Local", R.drawable.ic_location));
        navSpinner
                .add(new SpinnerNavItem("My Places", R.drawable.ic_my_places));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Checkins", R.drawable.ic_checkin));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Latitude", R.drawable.ic_latitude));

        // title drop down adapter
        adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navSpinner);
```

`getView()` and `getDropDownView()` from `TitleNavigationAdapter`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_title_navigation, null);
        }

        imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getIcon());
        imgIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_title_navigation, null);
        }

        imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getIcon());        
        txtTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }
```

*Download that code and u r good to go*

Comment: I would love to do this way. And I had already watched this tutorial. I should access the array of string only from xml file. You know the app is company's app, so when I am not here it should be reachable to change the items of spinner by anyone in future. Just trying to avoid to go into the source code.